# d3 - dashed line from a datapoint to an axis (seen in dimplejs.org)

Tags: d3.js

I would like to draw a dashed line from my datapoints to my X/Y axis (on mouseover). Thus, the value can be read better on the axis and it looks awesome (seen in the [dimple](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bubbles_vertical_grouped)).

I'm looking for a solution how can I achieve this or just an example.... 
Grateful for any tip!!

[image]

**Update 1**

It works and I can draw the lines. 
Now I want to draw it more animated - is that possible with *svg:line*?

```
var dpX = d3.select(this).attr('x');
var dpY = d3.select(this).attr('y');

                var myLine = d3Chart.append("svg:line")
                    .attr("class", 'd3-dp-line')
                    .attr("x1", dpX)
                    .attr("y1", dpY)
                    .attr("x2", 0)
                    .attr("y2", dpY)
                    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
                    .style("stroke-opacity", 0.9)
                    .style("stroke", dpChannel.Color);
```

Comment: I am looking for same feature!! Can i see ur code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot the lines with two points each:

- the horizontal line will have one point with coordinates (0, circleY)
  and (circleX, circleY)
- the vertical one will have (circleX,0) and    (circleX, circleY).

Where of course the `circleX` and `circleY` are the coordinates of the circle in the image

Comment: what do you mean by "more animated?" if you want them to go from the axis to the circle, you can set the initial points as 0,0 for both the points of the line and then transition them to the circle coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You can see exactly how dimple does it here: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/methods/_showPointTooltip.js Lines 65 - 106.  T

```
// Add a drop line to the x axis
if (dropDest.y !== null) {
    chart._tooltipGroup.append("line")
        .attr("x1", cx)
        .attr("y1", (cy < dropDest.y ? cy + r + series.lineWeight + 2 : cy - r - series.lineWeight - 2))
        .attr("x2", cx)
        .attr("y2", (cy < dropDest.y ? cy + r + series.lineWeight + 2 : cy - r - series.lineWeight - 2))
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", fill)
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
        .style("opacity", opacity)
        .transition()
        .delay(animDuration / 2)
        .duration(animDuration / 2)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("y2", (cy < dropDest.y ? dropDest.y - 1 : dropDest.y + 1));
}

// Add a drop line to the y axis
if (dropDest.x !== null) {
    chart._tooltipGroup.append("line")
        .attr("x1", (cx < dropDest.x ? cx + r + series.lineWeight + 2 : cx - r - series.lineWeight - 2))
        .attr("y1", cy)
        .attr("x2", (cx < dropDest.x ? cx + r + series.lineWeight + 2 : cx - r - series.lineWeight - 2))
        .attr("y2", cy)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", fill)
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
        .style("opacity", opacity)
        .transition()
        .delay(animDuration / 2)
        .duration(animDuration / 2)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("x2", (cx < dropDest.x ? dropDest.x - 1 : dropDest.x + 1));
    }
```

This clearly uses some internal dimple variables and functions but that is because I have to deal with a lot potential permutations. If you are coding a single chart you can replace these with fixed values.